# Slow aggregation in elasticsearch for low cardinality fields

Tags: elasticsearch

We use elasticsearch 7.2 and I have the two fields in my mapping

```
{
  "state": {
    "type": "long",
    "store": true,
    "null_value": 0
  }
}

{
  "csat": {
    "type": "integer",
    "store": true
  }
}
```

Average aggregation on `csat` field is super slow whereas average aggregation is super fast for `state` field. Both of these fields have only 5 type of values. In fact `csat` is a sparse field whereas `state` is a field in all my documents (~220495625 documents)

The Profile API showed slowness in `AvgAggregator` ES class, but i didn't see anything weird there except for fetching values from docvalues. Is it possible that for documents without csat field, the docvalue fetching is taking time perhaps? Hard to tell

Here is the hotthread of a node

```
96.5% (482.4ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[es7advcl02-14][search][T#8]'
     10/10 snapshots sharing following 39 elements
       app//org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene80.IndexedDISI.advanceExact(IndexedDISI.java:399)
       app//org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene80.Lucene80DocValuesProducer$SparseNumericDocValues.advanceExact(Lucene80DocValuesProducer.java:424)
       app//org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.FieldData$DoubleCastedValues.advanceExact(FieldData.java:446)
       app//org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.SingletonSortedNumericDoubleValues.advanceExact(SingletonSortedNumericDoubleValues.java:44)
       app//org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.metrics.AvgAggregator$1.collect(AvgAggregator.java:83)
       app//org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.LeafBucketCollector.collect(LeafBucketCollector.java:82)
       app//org.apache.lucene.search.MatchAllDocsQuery$1$1.score(MatchAllDocsQuery.java:64)
       app//org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:39)
       app//org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:652)
       app//org.apache.lucene.search.XIndexSearcher.search(XIndexSearcher.java:44)
       app//org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:177)
       app//org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:443)
       app//org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:271)
       app//org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:114)
       app//org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.lambda$loadIntoContext$18(IndicesService.java:1305)
       app//org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService$$Lambda$4388/0x0000000802064840.accept(Unknown Source)
       app//org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.lambda$cacheShardLevelResult$19(IndicesService.java:1362)
       app//org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService$$Lambda$4389/0x0000000802064c40.get(Unknown Source)
       app//org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesRequestCache$Loader.load(IndicesRequestCache.java:174)
       app//org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesRequestCache$Loader.load(IndicesRequestCache.java:157)
       app//org.elasticsearch.common.cache.Cache.computeIfAbsent(Cache.java:433)
       app//org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesRequestCache.getOrCompute(IndicesRequestCache.java:123)
       app//org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.cacheShardLevelResult(IndicesService.java:1368)
       app//org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.loadIntoContext(IndicesService.java:1302)
       app//org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.loadOrExecuteQueryPhase(SearchService.java:333)
       app//org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:360)
       app//org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.lambda$executeQueryPhase$1(SearchService.java:340)
       app//org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$$Lambda$4236/0x0000000802024040.apply(Unknown Source)
       app//org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener.lambda$map$2(ActionListener.java:145)
       app//org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$$Lambda$3643/0x0000000801dab040.accept(Unknown Source)
       app//org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$1.onResponse(ActionListener.java:62)
       app//org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$2.doRun(SearchService.java:1052)
       app//org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
       app//org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.TimedRunnable.doRun(TimedRunnable.java:44)
       app//org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:758)
       app//org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
       java.base@12.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
       java.base@12.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
       java.base@12.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Other weird thing I've observed is, the csat avg aggregation improved when I provided the  following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": "csat"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE,

Not just avg, but even terms aggregation is slow for csat

Comment: Can you try this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html ?

Comment: sure @AlkisKalogeris .. any idea how is it different than providing a query?

Comment: AFAIK it shouldn't... but I've never actually tested the differences. If you see a difference it would be interesting to investigate more

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of the conversation above, it's advisable to apply filters (`exists`, `date ranges`, `bucketing ranges` ...) whenever possible to narrow down your aggs, thereby speeding them up. You can observe the filters' effects by checking out the `took` millisecs in the response while ditching the cache and the individual `hits`, i.e:

```
GET my_index/_search?request_cache=false
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "csat"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "avg_agg": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "csat"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I totally agree. In 1.7, even without providing a query the response was quite fast. I'm sure a lot of things have changed by then